# Layout Swing alignment

Tags: java, swing

I need to create a layout like this:

```
------------------------------
|                             |
|               line1(right)  |
|  
|line2(left)                   
|
|
|  line3
|
|
|
|
------------------------------
```

where line3 is more than a line - it's a matrix of buttons. The size of the matrix needs to be fixed not like in GridLayout.

How to do that?

---

I came with a question:How to put the button on the front line?(Now he is in the middle)

```
Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
JButton button = new JButton("Button 1");
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
contentPane.add(button, c);
```

Comment: Do you have a question to ask?

Comment: GridBagLayout or MigLayout should suffice...

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Investigate the WindowBuilder feature.  Nice for laying out components.

Comment: Indeed. GridBagLayout... it would allow you to span cells where you needed more space. GBL is more verbose, but you get much more flexibility.

Comment: Ok, I'll test it but i do not need to resize buttons.

Answer (score 0):

A GridbagLayout should work:

For lines 1 and 2 you would need to specify the "anchor" constraint for each component you add

> where line3 is more than a line - it's a matrix of buttons

Then you would use a JPanel with whatever layout is appropriate for the buttons.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: For line1,line2 maybe i can use box1=Box.createHorizontalBox(); then need to do this:c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    contentPane.add(box1, c);  Is that right? or i need to make as many columns as exists in line1 and line2?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. If line 1 is really a panel of multiple components then you could use a FlowLayout with right aligment so all the components flow to the right. Read the tutorial there are exmaples for all the layout managers. You can nest panels with different layout managers as required.